# Code coverage in browser using selenium web driver and JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to know if there is any way to track code coverage of the html page that is being replayed(executed) using Selenium Web Driver and JAVA.

I mean if a user clicks on 2 buttons of 10 buttons in a page this has to be recorded and similar to buttons rest of the html elements has to be covered and finally a report has to be generated.

I execute .java file and ideally I want to see the code coverage of the user actions on the browser.

Thanks in Advance.